# Can't start anaconda-navigator and other: ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1: undefined symbol: _XEatDataWords

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

this is my first question on stackoverflow. Sorry for any customs violations ;)

I am running python3.6 on an Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Whenever I try to start anaconda-navigator or spyder on the terminal I get the following error:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1: undefined symbol: _XEatDataWords
```

The same happens when I try to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

in my python script.

I reinstalled anaconda navigator in different versions for different python versions and the ubuntu package libxxf86vm1_1.1.4-1_amd64.deb, but with no success.

Ist there someone with experience in this matter?

Best regards.

Comment: Maybe [\[linuxQuestions\]: undefined reference to '\_XEatDataWords'](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/undefined-reference-to-%60_xeatdatawords%27-4175525638) helps. Also, *Google* yields many similar results.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already tried this out. I am afraid I have to make some critical changes to the system, which I first thought I can avoid.